# scrolling not working with Tab in react native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, accessibility

I have data in flatList. I want to build app for people to use it with external keyboard by connecting keyboard with bluetooth.
But Now Problem is By pressing Tab button from keyboard FlatList Not scrolling till Bottom View Its only select views which present in current scree.
so is there any solution for this. please guide me over this

Comment: Hi can you please provide some code so that I can help you

Comment: Code is only FlatList No any code

Comment: check this one it's official page https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist